# Broadcom Wifi card (PCI-ID:14e4:43a0) not recognized on dual boot OSX/Kali

Tags: linux, macos, wireless-networking, drivers

I have a dual boot Mac with OSX and Kali Linux(1.0.7). Today I tried to get the Wifi working according to this guide:
    http://samiux.blogspot.de/2014/02/howto-kali-linux-106-on-macbook-air-mid.html
but it failed. Furthermore the b43 driver by Linux wireless does not seem to support the card(http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43)..
Do I have to buy an usb wifi device or is there some other possibility to get the wifi card working?

```
Chip ID:  BCM4360
PCI-ID:   14e4:43a0    
Broadcom Corporation
```

PS: It is NOT the "device not managed" error. iwconfig shows me no wireless only "lo".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [WikiDevi](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Broadcom_BCM94360CS2), the only Linux driver for this new chipset is Broadcom's original driver, *wl*, which you can download [from Broadcom's website](http://www.broadcom.com/support/802.11/linux_sta.php), [from Alberto Milone's PPA repository](https://launchpad.net/~albertomilone/+archive/broadcom), or from [Arch Linux's AUR package site](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/broadcom-wl-dkms/). All of them require linux headers and build essential, and the package from Arch Linux some extra control on missing dependencies.

Otherwise, installation is standard.

As for the driver you already have, you may check whether it is indeed suitable to your wifi card:

```
  modinfo wl | grep 14E4 | grep 43A0
```

(an empty output means it is not), whether it is mounted,

```
  sudo rmmod wl
  sudo modprobe wl
```

and, once it is mounted, what it is complaining about,

```
  dmesg | grep wlan0
```

These instructions also hold for the newer version, should you have any problem.